# UIScrollView is not behaving smoothly after adding customized buttons

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a UIScrollView in which i have more than 500 customized buttons and it can be up to a thousand depending on the requirement of a user. Actually, a subclass of UIButton. The reason I am using UIButton class is I have to perform some action on tap. The object looks like the following image

[image]

The arrangement of these buttons is like m*n matrix where row (m) is fixed to 20 but column (n) is not fixed. There can have 500 columns.

My problem is after adding buttons scrollView is not behaving smoothly. I used with the following code to create each each object

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        sizeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:sizeLabelRect];
        sizeLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:sizeLabelFontSize];
        sizeLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
//        sizeLabel.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:LABEL_BG_COLOR];
//        sizeLabel.layer.cornerRadius = CORNER_RADIUS;
        [self addSubview:sizeLabel];

        nFilesLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:nFilesLabelRect];
        nFilesLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:nFilesFontSize];
        nFilesLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
//        nFilesLabel.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:LABEL_BG_COLOR];
//        nFilesLabel.layer.cornerRadius = CORNER_RADIUS;
        [self addSubview:nFilesLabel];

        maxDisimilarity = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:disimilarityRect];
//        maxDisimilarity.layer.cornerRadius = CORNER_RADIUS;
        [self addSubview:maxDisimilarity];

//        nFragment = [[UILabel alloc] init];
//        nFragment.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:nFragmentFontSize];
//        [self addSubview:nFragment];
    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

- (void)setObj:(CloneClass *)obj
{
    NSString *colorCode;
    if (obj != nil) {
        _obj = obj;
        if ([_obj.type isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
            colorCode = COLOR;
        } else if ([_obj.type isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
            colorCode = COLOR;
        } else if ([_obj.obj isEqualToString:@"Type-3"]) {
            colorCode = COLOR;
        }
        self.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:colorCode];
        [self setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", obj.nFragments] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        // set size of clone class
        if (_obj.size > LARGE_SIZE) {
            sizeLabel.text = LARGE_SIZE_TEXT;
        } else if (_obj.size > MEDIUM_SIZE && _obj.size <= LARGE_SIZE) {
            sizeLabel.text = MEDIUM_SIZE_TEXT;
        } else {
            sizeLabel.text = SMALL_SIZE_TEXT;
        }

        // set number of files within a clone class
        nFilesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _cloneClass.nFiles];

        // set color for disimilarity
        CGFloat similarity = 1.0 - _cloneClass.maxDisimilarity;
        maxDisimilarity.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:similarity blue:similarity alpha:1.0];

    } else {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        [self setTitle:@"/" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

The scrollView is not even working for 10*10 matrix.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because you have added in a large number of custom elements, is my guess. How large is your scroll view? Can you modify your table to work vertically instead of horizontally and use a tabel view instead?

Comment: If i could modify my to work vertically, I could use UITableView to resolve this issue probably. Unfortunately, I have to control it horizontally.

Comment: Are you implementing ARC ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into `UICollectionView`. You're going to run into memory issues as it stands now.  `UICollectionView` allows you to create a `UICollectionViewCell` similar to `UITableViewCell`s that can be reused.

See the [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Keep in mind that `UICollectionView` wasn't added to the SDK until iOS 6.0 in case you need to support an earlier version of the OS.

Comment: That's very true.  I tend to be aggressive in pushing my OS versions, I forget not everyone is so lucky. :)

Comment: PSTCollectionView is a good drop in replacement for UICollectionView. It works the same in earlier version, and replaces itself with UICollectionView when it is available.

Comment: I will have to change lots of things if I try to use UICollectionView. Thanks anyway. Anything else I could try?

Comment: There's no easy fix without `UICollectionView`.  The number of objects you want to instantiate will mean handling your own cache of visible objects that free themselves when they are not visible and allocate themselves before they do become visible.  Which basically duplicates the functionality of what `UICollectionView` already does.